# sqoop import as parquet file to target dir, but can't find the file

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, parquet

I have been using sqoop to import data from mysql to hive, the command I used are below:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datasync \
    --username root --password 654321 \
    --query 'SELECT id,name FROM test WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by id \
    --hive-import --hive-database default --hive-table a \
    --target-dir /tmp/yfr --as-parquetfile
```

The Hive table is created and the data is inserted, however I can not find the parquet file.

Does anyone know?

Best regards,

Feiran

Comment: The data would be moved to the hive warehouse directory from `--target-dir`.

Comment: _"Hive table is created "_ -- just run a `show create table ***` command in Hive, the "LOCATION" clause will show where your data files are stored in HDFS.

Comment: Thank you, franklinsijo and  Samson Scharfrichter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqoop import to hive works in  2 steps:

- Fetching data from RDBMS to HDFS
- Create hive table if not exists and Load data into hive table

In your case,

firstly, data is stored at `--target-dir` i.e. `/tmp/yfr`

Then, it is loaded into Hive table `a` using

`LOAD DATA INPTH ... INTO TABLE..`
command.

As mentioned in the *comments*, data is moved to hive warehouse directory that's why there is no data in `--target-dir`.

Comment: Thanks, the file is truely in the warehouse:
/opt/data/hive/warehouse/chinacloud.db/aaaa/.metadata
/opt/data/hive/warehouse/chinacloud.db/aaaa/.signals
/opt/data/hive/warehouse/chinacloud.db/aaaa/be31fa3f-7bd3-406d-a9e5-b30240c9242c.parquet
/opt/data/hive/warehouse/chinacloud.db/aaaa/bfe43c8b-d5c4-4cde-819f-d52a7f210672.parquet
/opt/data/hive/warehouse/chinacloud.db/aaaa/d7e5deeb-594b-44b0-8abb-1990fa8fc17a.parquet

Comment: so, does that mean the --target-dir is kind of temporary location for the file?

Comment: @Feiran if you are doing import to HDFS only, your data will be in this location, in case of hive import yes, it is a temporary location.

Comment: Cheers     ,    mate      !